# Core Data - Sort descriptor for parent / child hierarchy

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I get a JSON object from a HTML request which contains a hierarchical structure.

Sample from JSON object:

```
{
    "_id": "4f870f064f95ae0da8000002",
    "name": "Category",
    "parent_id": null
},
{
    "_id": "4f870f0e4f95ae0da8000004",
    "name": "Brand",
    "parent_id": null
},
{
    "_id": "4f8715bd4f95ae0da8000028",
    "name": "Dermalogica",
    "parent_id": "4f870f0e4f95ae0da8000004"
},
{
    "_id": "4f8715de4f95ae0da800002a",
    "name": "Molton Brown",
    "parent_id": "4f870f0e4f95ae0da8000004"
},
{
    "_id": "4f8715ea4f95ae0da800002c",
    "name": "Waxing",
    "parent_id": "4f870f064f95ae0da8000002"
},
{
    "_id": "4f8715f34f95ae0da800002e",
    "name": "Mens Hair",
    "parent_id": "4f870f064f95ae0da8000002"
},
{
    "_id": "4f8715fd4f95ae0da8000030",
    "name": "Ladies Hair",
    "parent_id": "4f870f064f95ae0da8000002"
},
{
    "_id": "4f87161f4f95ae0da8000032",
    "name": "Massage",
    "parent_id": "4f870f064f95ae0da8000002"
}
```

When I save it in the same way in just one entity, how would I define the fetch request (sorting) so that the objects are sorted with their parent / child relation ?

Comment: Are you going to parse it and save it to 8 objects of one entity,each having three attributes?What are you going to sort by then?Please,explain

Comment: Yes, exactly what I would do. I parse it in separate 'NSManagedObjects' stored in one single entity. As there is no particular order when I receive them, they are not ordered hierarchically within the entity. Especially as I fetch for updates and receive just single updated objects with a UID reference. When I fetch for the 'NSFetchedResultsController' I want to sort them into the logical hierarchical parent/child order (and overall alphabetically within parents ...). Does this make sense to you ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to sort this kind of data using sortDescriptors.
This is how I solve the problem, having comments of article with threaded style discussions. After I download all comments, I need to `reindexComments`

```
-(void)reindexComments{
    NSArray *articleComments = self.comments.allObjects;
    [self fetchChildsWithComments:articleComments forParentId:0 num:1];
}

-(NSUInteger)fetchChildsWithComments:(NSArray*)articleComments forParentId:(NSUInteger)parentId num:(NSUInteger)num{
    NSArray *childComments = [articleComments filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parentId == %u", parentId]];
    childComments = [childComments sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Comment *c1, Comment *c2) {
        if (c1.commentIdValue < c2.commentIdValue){
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        }else{
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        }
    }];

    for (Comment *newRootComment in childComments){
        newRootComment.numValue = num;
        num++;
        num = [self fetchChildsWithComments:articleComments forParentId:newRootComment.commentIdValue num:num];
    }
    return num;
}
```

and finally I just sort by `numValue` field to get my nice threaded discussion

Answer (score -1):

One Way - to use NSOrderedSet - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Second,more convinient(since NSOrderedSet is introduced in iOS 5),just a soimple NSFetchRequest with sortDescriptors.Since it is an Array, you can use a many descritors at a time as you want. So, using descriptors by **parent_id** and **id** should give you desired result.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Child" inManagedObjectContext:context];
   // request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent_id =  %@",parent_ID];You don't need any predicate,right?
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"parent_id" ascending:YES],[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"_id" ascending:YES],nil];

return [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

And,in Objective-C it's not convinient to use underlines in names.
Hope, that helps.

Comment: Your suggested sortDescriptor as sorts just for the "_id" of the objects but does not take care about sorting in the children accordingly to their "parent_id". This would actually be the question as it is no problem to get a fetchRequest just sorted by one attribute. Any idea how to define the sortDescriptor to take care about this parent / child relation ?

Comment: So.You want to make a fetch to all the children enteties.With all the parent_ids.Right?And sort them first by their _ids and then by their parent_ids?Really ant to understand and help you)

Comment: You feel like array of sortdescriptors(by _id and parent_id) won't help you too?

Comment: See my answer with multiple descriptors

Comment: Ok, as I understand there is no way to do this in one go ...
Possible solution would therefore be:
1. Fetch highest level (that do not have parents)
2. Fetch rest (that do have parents)
3. Enumerate through highest level objects and add children from 2nd fetch enumerating through the hierarchy
Basically build an Array out of 2 fetch requests ...

What do you mean with "See my answer with multiple descriptors" ?

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: Array of descriptors is really a one go way.Or i don't understand your question again?